# declaring namespace attribute in XSD element

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces, attributes

I am using inbuilt feature in eclipse to generate an XML file from XSD.
XML has to be generated as given below, with 'addressbook' under a different namespace.

```
<employee xmlns:ns2="urn:employees_2014_1.lists.webservices.test.com">
    <department>8029</department>
    <emailAddress>USER_17@something.com</emailAddress>
    <employeeAddressBookList>
        <ns2:addressbook>
            <ns2:addressee>BC</ns2:addressee>
            <ns2:addr1>A1</ns2:addr1>
            <ns2:addr2>A2</ns2:addr2>
            <ns2:city>C1</ns2:city>
            <ns2:state>ST1</ns2:state>
            <ns2:zip>10001</ns2:zip>
        </ns2:addressbook>
    </employeeAddressBookList>
    <employeeId>000001</employeeId>
</employee>
```

My XSD is as given below.

```
    <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xsd:element name="employee">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="department" type="xsd:int" />
            <xsd:element name="emailAddress" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="employeeAddressBookList">
              <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="ns2:addressbook">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                      <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="ns2:addressee" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element name="ns2:addr1" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element name="ns2:addr2" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element name="ns2:city" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element name="ns2:state" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element name="ns2:zip" type="xsd:int" />
                      </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                  </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="employeeId" type="xsd:int" />
          </xsd:sequence>
<xsd:attribute name="xmlns:ns2" type="xs:string" />
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
```

This generated an XML with out the namespace value.

```
<employee xmlns:ns2="">
    <department>8029</department>
    <emailAddress>USER_17@something.com</emailAddress>
    <employeeAddressBookList>
        <ns2:addressbook>
            <ns2:addressee>BC</ns2:addressee>
            <ns2:addr1>A1</ns2:addr1>
            <ns2:addr2>A2</ns2:addr2>
            <ns2:city>C1</ns2:city>
            <ns2:state>ST1</ns2:state>
            <ns2:zip>10001</ns2:zip>
        </ns2:addressbook>
    </employeeAddressBookList>
    <employeeId>000001</employeeId>
</employee>
```

I am talking about this line...

```
<employee xmlns:ns2="">
```

How do i add value to the namespace?

Answer (score 1):

That XSD has so many problems that it's surprising that you're getting any XML from it:

1. Namespace declarations are not attributes.
2. Element `@name` attribute values must be NCNAMEs (without a namespace
   prefix).
3. You cannot have both namespaced (`addressbook` and descendents) and
   non-namespaced (`employee`, `department`, etc) components declared
   in a single XSD -- you'll need to use `xsd:import`.

Without making (at least) the above repairs to your XSD, you can't expect correct XML to be generated from it.

Comment: that's weird.. I do not have an option to declare and import another XSD since this schema is going to be a database entry. it is like, i am using a 3rd party system to show these information on UI. They will read the XML and display the data. If UI user modifies the content, application will fetch the schema from DB and create a new XML with modified value. I cannot change that system. So only option i have is to change the XML to use default schema for all elements..

Comment: If your system doesn't allow you to have two schema documents in your schema, for different namespaces, then it doesn't allow you to have a multi-namespace document instance, because xs:import is the ONLY way of achieving this.